# How do you search for a specific english word

Tags: research

Consider that you are writing a blog post or an essay.  No one will have all the words we need at the tip of the tongue at all times. So when you struggle to find the appropriate word, what resource do you use to find the appropriate word?

There are more than one ways to find a specific word.  One is where we know a related word and look for its synonym/antonym. For example the word 'beautiful' is so overused, you would like to use a synonymous word which is more exact.  The other is finding a related word where we know the surrounding context and try to use the appropriate word for that context. For example "a ________ pupil" you might want to describe a person who is a perfect pupil disciplined and intelligent. So how do you go about this type of search?

Do most of your search fall into 'synonymous' type or 'related words' type?

Comment: Google "synonym xxx" and then keep poking.

Comment: Yep, that is the usual way we search for synonyms, I suppose. But how do you go about looking for related words?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources, and not a question about the English language itself.

Comment: Wasn't this what they created a [thesaurus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thesaurus) for, in the days before Google?

Comment: Before starting to search for anything, why not capitalize "english" in the subject?

Comment: Synonyms of synonyms.  And as oerkelens suggests, an old-fashioned thesaurus is often helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many visual word dictionaries popping up on the internet. You may consider using visuwords.com or wordnet.princeton.edu . Others include the Word Association Network and SnappyWords. Mileage may vary. Just try popping onto a search engine of your choice and entering "visual dictionary."